# How to populate h2 memory table with a Real Database Table?

Tags: java, spring, redis, h2

I hope i can explain this in a proper way.

I have a Sql Server Database with serveral tables.
In my Spring - Boot application,i need to query to those tables,there are a couple of tables that wont change ever.

For example,lets suppose for simplicity it s a Book table,and i query the books in different ways,by price,by id,by ISBN ,what ever.

So first thing i thought ,it s to use Redis,but that s not good for me.Why?

Well,Redis stores the data in a key-value pair,so if i catch the entire table,then in my code when i want to do same complex query to that data (Give me the book with this ISBN),that s not possible,i will need to create different Catched methods for each operations,so the next time i ask for same data ,if exist in the cache,it wont go to query to the Database.

Thats why i though about H2 memory database,i could fill my "Book" in memory table and make all kind of operation on it,because it works like a normal database and i could query anything.

**Now,comes my questiion:**

I know i can load initial data into H2 pointing to some script,that s ok.
But i would like to populate my "Book" in memory database,with the same data that i already have in my SQL Server Book table.

What do you think? Is that possible?Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement CommandLineRunner or ApplicationRunner for data initialization
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-applicationrunner-and-commandlinerunne

(Also script.sql in resources with "spring.datasource.data=script.sql" property could be used for data load)

Comment: Hi.Yes i know that,but how do i generate script.sql at runtime??